# Using Gmap4Rails Gem No Error but Map is not getting displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Hi I am currently going through this tutorial using gmap4rails

http://andyglassblog.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/google-maps-for-rails-with-gmaps4-rails-tutorial-on-how-to-post-and-filter-locations/

I am quite new to this gem so I am just going through the guide step by step.

I have a cities_controller.rb

```
 class CitiesController < ApplicationController
        def index
        @cities = City.all
        @json = @cities.to_gmaps4rails
        end
    end
```

I have a city.rb for my model

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base 
    acts_as_gmappable

    has_many :neighborhoods 

    def gmaps4rails_address
        "#{self.name}, #{self.state}"
    end

end
```

This is my index.html.erb within my cities folder inside my view folder

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

I added the gem ran the installer as well.

In my application layout, I have this in my body

```
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

This is my schema

```
 ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20130714194244) do

      create_table "cities", force: true do |t|
        t.string   "name"
        t.string   "state"
        t.float    "latitude"
        t.float    "longitude"
        t.boolean  "gmaps"
        t.datetime "created_at"
        t.datetime "updated_at"
        t.integer  "population"
      end
```

I am actually getting no errors, I seeded the database with these

```
  City.create(name: "New york" ,state: "NY", population: 8175133)
    City.create(name: "Los Angeles",state: "CA", population: 3792621 )
    City.create(name: "Chicago",state: "IL", population: 2695598)
    City.create(name: "Houston",state: "TX", population: 2099451)
    City.create(name: "Philadelphia",state: "PA" , population: 1526006)
    City.create(name: "Phoenix",state: "AZ", population: 1445632)
    City.create(name: "San Antonio",state: "TX", population: 1327407)
    City.create(name: "San Diego",state: "CA", population: 1307402 )
    City.create(name: "Dallas",state: "TX", population: 1197816)
    City.create(name: "San Jose",state: "CA", population: 945942)
```

When I open my rails console and do City.all

I noticed that the latitude and longitude has been calculated for me which means the gem is working properly.

```
#<City id: 1, name: "New york", state: "NY", latitude: 40.7143528, longitude: -74.00597309999999, gmaps: true, created_at: "2013-07-14 19:51:32", updated_at: "2013-07-14 19:51:32", population: 8175133>
```

Am I missing some api key? when I do rails s all I get is a blank screen? At the minimum I should be seeing a map. It could be a js problem, I am not quite sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Check your `app/assets/javascripts` folder, do you have a `gmaps4rails` folder? Also, can you post your content for  `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`?

Comment: @David hey I got it, it has been resolved. turns out that the gem got problems with ruby 2.0 and rails 4. I switched back to ruby 1.9.3p429 and rails 3.2.13. The js files were originally created in my public's folder which isn't correct, it should have been generated in my assets folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use gmaps4rails with rails 4.0 yet, there is a turbolink issue. Multiple users are having rails 4.0 problems on the issues page on gmaps4rails repo. The js files were generated into my public folder when I ran the generate command using rails 4. I switched back to 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3p429 now the js files are getting generated in my assets folder.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution! Feel free to accept your own answer :o)